# Apply ngClass on Each Section

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ng-class

I have done Implementing all the UI part. that looks

[image]

and my data is

```
public filters = [
    {
      tag: 'Year',
      label: 'year',
      items: [2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]
    },
    {
      tag: 'Cash On Delivery',
      label: 'cash',
      items: this.truthyFalsy
    },
    {
      tag: 'In stock',
      label: 'stock',
      items: this.truthyFalsy
    }
  ];
```

and my html code is

```
      <div *ngFor="let filter of filters">
        <p ><small>{{filter?.tag}}</small></p>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div>
          <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of filter?.items">
            <button class="btn" [ngClass]="{'btn-active-1':labelType1 === filter.label  && selectedItem === item }"
              (click)="select(item,filter?.label)">{{item}}</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and on selected button I have to make it active.

The actually my requirement is

1. in **`year section`** I have to make any one active
2. in  **`Cash On delivery`** I have to make any one active
3. and in **`In stock`** I have to make any one active

In each section I have to make it at least one button should be active using **`ngClass`**

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample for you here on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gjq3rg?file=src/app/app.component.html).

You can use `let i = index` to select items by index and have default selected item. So, try this to select the first item in each group:

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  labelType1: string = "";
  public selectedItem = { year : 0, cash: 0, stock: 0  };
  truthyFalsy: any[] = [true, false];
  public filters = [
    {
      tag: 'Year',
      label: 'year',
      items: [2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]
    },
    {
      tag: 'Cash On Delivery',
      label: 'cash',
      items: this.truthyFalsy
    },
    {
      tag: 'In stock',
      label: 'stock',
      items: this.truthyFalsy
    }
  ];

  select(index, label){
    this.selectedItem[label] = index;
  }
}
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let filter of filters">
    <p><small>{{filter?.tag}}</small></p>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div>
        <div class="item" *ngFor="let i=index; let item of filter?.items">
            <button class="btn" [ngClass]="{'btn-active-1': selectedItem[filter.label] === i}" (click)="select(i,filter?.label)">{{item}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yybw8g?)

On button click you could pass item index and label to distinguish all types of section and their button.

```
 /* initialize empty object of selectedItem where we can set key(lable)
 and value(index) on each button click from key(label) and value(index)
 we can identify the selected button of each section */
 selectedItem = {};
```

`select` method toggle on button if user clicks on already selected button it will remove selected button else make button selected.

```
  select(index, label) {
    if(this.selectedItem[label] === index) {
      delete this.selectedItem[label]
    } else {
      this.selectedItem = {
      ...this.selectedItem,
     [label]: index
   };
  }
}
```

In template all you need to pass `index` and `label` from `select` method and add conditional active class by putting `[class.btn-active-1]="selectedItem[filter.label] === i"`

```
 <div *ngFor="let filter of filters;">
    <p ><small>{{filter?.tag}}</small></p>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div>
      <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of filter?.items; let i=index">
        <button class="btn" [class.btn-active-1]="selectedItem[filter.label] === i"
          (click)="select(i,filter?.label)">{{item}}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```